# How to structure module to be closer/adhere to Node.js philosophy

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am relatively new to Node.js and I am trying to get more familiar with it by writing a simple module. The module's purpose is take an id, scrape a website and return an array of dictionaries with the data.

The data on the website is scattered across pages whereas every page is accessed by a different index number in the URI. I've defined a function that takes the `id` and `page_number`, scrapes the website via `http.request()` for this `page_number` and on `end` event the data is passed to another function that applies some RegEx to get the data in a structured way.

In order for the module to have complete functionality, all the available `page_nums` of the website should be scraped.

Is it ok by Node.js style/philosophy to create a standard for() loop to call the scraping function for every page, aggregate the results of every return and then return them all in once from the exported function?

**EDIT**

I figured out a solution based on help from #node.js on freenode. You can find the working code at http://github.com/attheodo/katina_node

Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: If it is different to the answers given here, please add your own answer and select it as the chosen answer so that others can benefit in the future - thanks.

Comment: I can see why you've chosen that as an answer but I can't say that it follows Node's philosophy which was your question. It does a recursive call but doesn't place any limits on recursion which is very dangerous. Also, I'm certain this wouldn't scale so it is OK for your own use but I wouldn't make it public as it could easily bring down your server.

Comment: @JulianKnight feel free to fork it, make your changes and send me a pull request. I think it will be a great opportunity for everyone to learn from that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helpful comments from #node.js on Freenode I managed to find a solution by sequentially calling the scraping function and attaching callbacks, as Node.js philosophy requires.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/attheodo/katina_node/blob/master/lib/katina.js

The code block of interest lies between lines 87 and 114.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The common method, if you don't want to bother with one of the libraries mentioned by @ControlAltDel, is to to set a counter equal to the number of pages. As each page is processed (ansynchronously so you don't know in what order, nor do you care), you decrement the counter. When the counter is zero, you know you've processed all pages and can move on to the next part of the process.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I guess it makes sense if you know how many of these pages are in total in the first place. In my case I don't and I still have to make the request and parse the XML to check if a specific part of it is actually populated. If I used a while(1) loop to call the scraping function with incremental page numbers, since the requests would be executed async there could be a case where the last request (the empty response one) would return before a previous one does and thus break the loop. I would be missing some data though. :/

Comment: Ah, foolish me, I assumed that you would know how many pages there were. This would only work if you could easily find out the number of pages before needing to parse them. How *are* you going to work out when you have finished? What tells you that you have all the pages you need? Is there a table of contents?

Comment: I convert the returning XML into JSON for easier manipulation. If the specific part I am looking for in each page is missing, I'll get an exception when trying to access it using the native array and dictionary methods. Then I'll know it's the last page.

Comment: OK, different question. Where do you get the list of pages from? Are you following a link on each page, or are all of the pages listed on a single index page?

Comment: I am incrementing a parameter named page_num via GET. So they are different, exclusive requests.

Comment: So you are saying that you **have** to process the pages sequentially because you don't know - and have no way of working out in advance - how many pages there are except after processing a page that doesn't return the data you want.

Comment: If the above is true, then you are somewhat limited in what you can do. The slowest but easiest way is to process each page sequentially using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library or similar. A faster way would be to maintain a `completed` flag set to `false` until the you have a page that you can't process. Then to run several parallel worker threads. Once the flag is true and all worker threads complete, then you can continue with the processing. This is best done through an event since the event handler will do nothing until triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will probably encounter is recombining all of the aggregated results. There are several libraries out there that can help, including Async and Step. Or you can use a promises library like Fibers.Promise. But the latter is not really node philosophy and requires direct code changes / additions to the node executable.